# Can't bind lvalue to rvalue reference

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference

I have this C++ test code snippet,

```cpp
#include <vector>

class A {
        std::vector<int> x;
public:
        A(std::vector<int>&& _x) : x(_x) {}
};

class B {
        A a;
public:
        B(std::vector<int>&& _x) : a(/*move(*/_x/*)*/) {}
};
```

I'm passing `_x` to B as rvalue reference, but it's getting converted to lvalue when passed into `A`'s constructor and I have to use `std::move()` to make it work. My question is why _x is lvalue and not an rvalue reference in `a()`?

Comment: While the type of `_x` is 'r-value reference to std::vector<int>', it is still an l-value  as it has a name. You might want to use it more than once in your constructor, so it shouldn't be moved from on first use unless you explicitly want to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quote from [WIKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Rvalue_references_and_move_constructors)

*For safety reasons, some restrictions are imposed. **A named variable will never be considered to be an rvalue even if it is declared as such. To get an rvalue, the function template std::move()** should be used. Rvalue references can also be modified only under certain circumstances, being intended to be used primarily with move constructors.*

Comment: Wikipedia is imprecise here. Type and value category are two orthogonal concepts; you cant *declare* the value category. E.g. the result of the expression `dynamic_cast<SomeClass&>(someObject)` is of type `lvalue-reference to SomeClass`, but it is an r-value.

Answer (score 8):

Anything that has a name is an lvalue reference.  You have to use std::move on parameters to pass them on as rvalue references.

Comment: Shouldn't *Anything that has a name is an lvalue reference* be *Anything that has a name is an lvalue*?