# Unable to bind rvalue reference arguments in member function

Tags: pybind11

I'm using pybind11 to create python bindings for a C++ library whose source I cannot change.  It contains a class that defines member functions with rvalue reference arguments (eg `T &&val`).  I am unable to create a binding to a member function with rvalue reference arguments but binding to a non-member function with identical arguments works as expected.

A simplified example looks like this:

```
struct Foo {
    // Cannot create a pybinding for this method.
    void print_ref(int &&v) const {
            std::cout << "Foo::print_ref(" <<  to_string(v) << ")" <<std::endl;
    }
};
// Pybinding for standalone function works as expected.
void print_ref(int&& val) {
        std::cout << "print_ref(" << to_string(val) << ")" << std::endl;
};
```

The pybind11 code looks like this:

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(refref, m) {
    py::class_<Foo>(m, "Foo")
    // Both of these attempts to create a pybinding FAILs with same error.
    .def("print_ref", &Foo::print_ref)
    .def("print_ref", (void (Foo::*) (int&&)) &Foo::print_ref);
    // This pybinding of standalone function is SUCCESSful.
    m.def("print_ref", &print_ref);
}
```

The compilation error on the first binding attempt is:

```
pybind11/bin/../include/site/python3.4/pybind11/pybind11.h:79:80: error: rvalue reference to type 'int' cannot bind to lvalue of type 'int'
        initialize([f](const Class *c, Arg... args) -> Return { return (c->*f)(args...); },
                                                                               ^~~~
pybind11/bin/../include/site/python3.4/pybind11/pybind11.h:1085:22: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'pybind11::cpp_function::cpp_function<void, Foo, int &&,
      pybind11::name, pybind11::is_method, pybind11::sibling>' requested here
        cpp_function cf(method_adaptor<type>(std::forward<Func>(f)), name(name_), is_method(*this),
                     ^
refref.cpp:31:3: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'pybind11::class_<Foo>::def<void (Foo::*)(int &&) const>' requested here
        .def("print_ref", &Foo::print_ref);
```

Any ideas on what I may be doing wrong?  Since it works fine with non-member functions, I'm inclined to suspect a pybind11 issue but thought I would check here first.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, the problem comes from `rvalues`. I learned quite a few things from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40350289/3283333) and [this blog post](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_02.html).
There's a nice workaround : you can create a wrapper class that will redirect calls to the C++ library you cannot change, taking care of the `rvalue` with the `std::move` semantic.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/numpy.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

struct Foo {
    void print_ref(int&& v) const {
            std::cout << "Foo::print_ref("  <<  +v << ")" <<std::endl;
    }
};


// This class will interface between PyBind and your library
class Foo_wrap{
private:
  Foo _mimu;
public:
  void print_ref(int v) const{
    _mimu.print_ref(std::move(v));
  }
};



PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
     py::class_<Foo_wrap>(m, "Foo_wrap")
     .def(py::init())
     .def("print_ref", &Foo_wrap::print_ref);
}
```

That you can call in Python with

```
import example as fo

wr = fo.Foo_wrap()
wr.print_ref(2)
```