# Why call to overloaded overridden function with universal or r-value reference is ambiguous?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, forwarding-reference

I have a problem related to reference forwarding, to which I am only slightly familiar with. Before stating my question, I want to say that I've read a few pages related to this language feature and they kind of confused me rather than shedding light into my problem. The consulted references are: [[1](https://www.codesynthesis.com/%7Eboris/blog/2012/06/26/efficient-argument-passing-cxx11-part2/)-[5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5465371/1876268)], some of which I find contradictory or don't fully understand. Aware of the fact that this question could be considered a duplicate, I am posting it anyways because I couldn't find a case that would combine these three factors:

- Overloaded functions with r-value references.
- Templated classes (not functions).
- Override of overloaded functions where the parent class' function is called in the overrides.

### Problem scenario

I have two classes that I use to represent a variable of a model. The generic one is `MState<T>` and I template it because I want it to wrap any possible type inside. It's more like a wrapper to a type that I have created for a purpose which is irrelevant to this question. Then, I have `MOutput<T>`, which essentially extends `MState<T>` and represents an externally visible variable of a user-defined model.

They both have a member function called `setValue` which allows to, well... set their value. I know it would be nices to implement operator semantics, but for now I'm dealing with this:

```
template <class T>
class MState
{
public:
    virtual void setValue(T value) {      // -- (A)
        m_state = value;
        // (... more things.)
    }
    virtual void setValue(T&& value) {    // -- (B)
        m_state = value;
        // (... more things.)
    }
    T getValue(void) { return m_state; }
protected:
    T m_state;
};

template <class T>
class MOutput : public MState<T>
{
public:
    void setValue(T value) override {                     // -- (C)
        MState<T>::setValue(std::forward<T>(value));
        // (... even more things.)
    }
    void setValue(T&& value) override {                   // -- (D)
        MState<T>::setValue(std::forward<T>(value));
        // (... even more things.)
    }
};
```

I think I need (A) to allow for l-values to be valid arguments in calls to `MState::setValue`. Actually, if I remove it the compiler complains that it cannot convert an l-value to an r-value reference (which I understood with [[4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40350289/1876268)].) However, I want to avoid unnecessary resource allocations and copies, especially when dealing with temporaries (e.g. `ms.setValue(MyClass())`.) Hence (B).

Likewise, (C) is necessary because I need `MOutput`'s to do a few things more, in addition to the ones `MState` implements. For the same motivation above, I also want (D).

The use of `std::forward<T>(value)` in (C) and (D) is motivated by [[3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3582313/1876268)].

### Question

When I try to compile my code, GCC complains about the overloaded function signature to be ambiguous in both classes and a number of cases. I think I don't understand why, or how to solve the issue. Is `T&&` here a universal reference? If so, shouldn't these accept any kind of argument type?

#### Use cases

GCC fails to compile the line `MState<T>::setValue(std::forward<T>(value));` of both (C) and (D). If I comment them out, I get the same ambiguity error in these cases:

```
bool function(int a) { return a >= 1; }
MOutput<bool> vo0, vo1, vo2;
vo1.setValue(true);                                // Error.
vo2.setValue(false);                               // Error.
vo0.setValue(!(vo1.getValue() & vo2.getValue()));  // Error.

MOutput<int> vo3;
vo3.setValue(432);                                 // Error.
```

### Consulted references

1. [https://www.codesynthesis.com/~boris/blog/2012/06/26/efficient-argument-passing-cxx11-part2/](https://www.codesynthesis.com/%7Eboris/blog/2012/06/26/efficient-argument-passing-cxx11-part2/)
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31551595/1876268
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3582313/1876268
4. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40350289/1876268
5. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5465371/1876268

Comment: You should be using `std::forward` when dealing with templates. And let it do the proper conversion.

Comment: FWIW, `T&& value` is not a universal reference since `T`'s type is known (it is the class template type).  `T&& value` is only a universal reference when `T` is a template parameter for the function itself.

Comment: To accept an lvalue, use `const T&`. To accept an rvalue, use `const T&`. One function. Problem solved.

Comment: What if I want to allow temporaries (and want to avoid unnecessary resource allocations and copies) @PeteBecker?

Comment: Hopefully it will now be MCV @FrançoisAndrieux. Thanks!

Comment: Again: `const T&`. Try it.

Comment: I may have missed your point. Are you looking to **move from** rvalues? If so, two overloads: one `const T&` and one `T&&`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply have simple `void setValue(const T& value)` (even more when your getter does copy).

But if you want both l-value reference, and r-value reference, it would be something like:

```
template <class T>
class MState
{
public:
    virtual void setValue(const T& value) {
        m_state = value;
        MoreStuff()
    }
    virtual void setValue(T&& value) {
        m_state = std::move(value);
        MoreStuff()
    }
    const T& getValue() const { return m_state; }
private:
    void MoreStuff();
protected:
    T m_state;
};

template <class T>
class MOutput : public MState<T>
{
public:
    void setValue(const T& value) override {
        MState<T>::setValue(value);
        MoreThings();
    }
    void setValue(T&& value) override {
        MState<T>::setValue(std::move(value));
        MoreThings();
    }
private:
    void MoreThings();
};
```

> Is T&& here a universal reference?

As state, in comment, no it isn't, `T` is fixed by the class.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that in this case, it can't tell whether it should make a copy of T, or pass it in via an rvalue reference, thus the ambiguity.  Try taking a const reference to T for the first function.

Also std::forward is intended for when you're doing universal reference (rvalue references in a deduced context), I don't believe it applies here.